Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$testArray"
I'm currently getting an error on my Privacy Policy page of my Wordpress site that looks like this:
Privacy Policy Page
This my code for page.php. I'm currently stumped myself. It looks just like the instructor's.
<?php 
 
    get_header();
 
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post(); ?>
        
        
        <div class="page-banner">
      <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri("/images/ocean.jpg") ?>)"></div>
      <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
        <h1 class="page-banner__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="page-banner__intro">
          <p>DON'T FORGET TO REPLACE ME LATER</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
 
      <?php 
        $theParent = wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID());
        if($theParent) { ?>
          <div class="container container--narrow page-section">
      <div class="metabox metabox--position-up metabox--with-home-link">
        <p>
          <a class="metabox__blog-home-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink($theParent); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Back to <?php echo get_the_title($theParent); ?></a> <span class="metabox__main"><?php echo the_title(); ?></span>
        </p>
      </div>
        <?php }
      ?>
 
    
      <? php 
      $testArray = get_pages(array(
        "child_of" => get_the_ID()
      ));
      
      if($theParent or $testArray) { ?>
      <div class="page-links">
        <h2 class="page-links__title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($theParent); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($theParent); ?></a></h2>
        <ul class="min-list">
          <?php 
          if($theParent) {
            $findChildrenOF = $theParent;
          } else {
            $findChildrenOF = get_the_ID();
          }
 
            wp_list_pages(array(
              "title_li" => NULL,
              "child_of" => $findChildrenOF
            ));
          ?>
        </ul>
      </div> 
      <?php } ?>
 
      <div class="generic-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
 
    <?php }
 
    get_footer();
 
?>

I googled "unexpected variable", expecting to find something relevant, but that did not happen.


Please post the error as text, not as picture. 2. You can spot the line 34 using a variable which is not set.


<? php  should not have any spaces
